# Joomla make payment with paypal and track the payment

Tags: php, joomla, paypal

i have a joomla site and in one article page, i want to sell a book of myne.

My users will be visiting this page, and when they click on "Buy" link, they will be shown a form, where they can fill details like name, email, phone and address.

Upon submitting the form, i want the user details to be inserted into the database, and then redirect the users to paypal site, for making a small payment towards the purchase.

How can i accomplish this?

I have heard about Chrono forms in joomla, but cant seem to figure out how to do 2 things simultaneoudly (inserting user details in db, and redirecting to paypal site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got the [Simple Caddy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart/4148) component from joomla extensions, and it is working well.

It perfectly suits my needs. However i could not use the paypal sandbox with this...